# System.Diagnostics.EventLog doesn't contain correct message

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, event-log, system.diagnostics

In some cases, when retrieving event logs from `System.Diagnostics.EventLog`, message like this

```
The description for Event ID '10016' in Source 'DCOM' cannot be found...
```

is returned. I found out that this response is also returned by `Get-EventLog` command in Powershell.

The actual message should look like this:

```
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission...
```

and is returned by `Get-WinEvent` command.

Is there any way to retrieve the second message in .Net Framework project? (without calling an independent Powershell script)?

**UPDATE**

I implemented the suggested solution, but now I stumbled on a different problem - how can I retrieve Audit Success and Audit Failure information? The EventLogEntry had an enum that contained them, but EventRecord doesn't

**Update 2**

I found a way to deal with Audits. EventRecord has a Keywords property, I compared it to StandardEventKeywords enum

Comment: You could try and mimic what `Get-WinEvent` does: enumerate events with an [`EventLogReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogreader), then call [`FormatDescription()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventrecord.formatdescription) on the resulting events to render the message

Comment: I'll look into it, sadly the examples in docs are in VB so this could take a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `Get-WinEvent` uses the [`EventLogReader` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogreader) to enumerate the events queried, and then calls [`EventRecord.FormatDescription()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventrecord.formatdescription) on each resulting record to render the localized message.

Here's a sample console application to fetch and print the rendered message of each of the first 10 Warning (`Level=3`) events in the `Application` log:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // construct an EventLogQuery object from a log path + xpath query
        var xpath = "*[System[Level=3]]";
        var query = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, xpath);

        // instantiate an EventLogReader over the query
        var reader = new EventLogReader(query);

        // read the events one by one
        var counter = 0;
        EventRecord record = null;
        while ((record = reader.ReadEvent()) is EventRecord && ++counter <= 10)
        {
            // call FormatDescription() to render the message in accordance with your computers locale settings
            var renderedMessage = record.FormatDescription();
            Console.WriteLine(renderedMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Beware that it's entirely possible for `FormatDescription()` to return an empty string - this will occur when the event logging provider didn't provide a message template for the given event id.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

You can try and mimic what `Get-WinEvent` does: enumerate events with an `EventLogReader`, then call `FormatDescription()` on the resulting events to render the message

You can refer to [EventLogReader Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogreader?view=net-5.0) and [EventRecord.FormatDescription Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventrecord.formatdescription?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Mathias R. Jensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen), I created something similar using XML query

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string logName = "System";
        string sourceName = "DCOM";
        string query = $@"<QueryList>
                          <Query Id=""0"" Path=""{logName}"">
                            <Select Path=""{logName}"">
                                *[System[Provider[@EventSourceName=""{sourceName}""]]]
                                and
                                *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;=""{DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-10).ToString("O")}""]]]
                            </Select>
                          </Query>
                        </QueryList>";

        EventLogQuery elq = new EventLogQuery("System", PathType.LogName, query);
        EventLogReader elr = new EventLogReader(elq);

        EventRecord entry;
        while ((entry = elr.ReadEvent()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.FormatDescription());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```